# What is the difference between mongod and Service of mongodb run in windows services

Tags: json, database, mongodb, bson, mongo-shell

Recently I started learning Mongodb.
After the installation I ran the
**> mongo**
command and without starting the daemon ie the **mongod** and even without starting the the daemon it ran perfectly and i was able to do all the **CRUD** operations

Later I tried running **mongod** first and then **mongo** command and was able to perform all the same operations

So my question is that how come I was able to run **mongo** without starting the daemon ??

Comment: It's probably started automatically, as configured during installation.

Comment: mongod is a server binary that can be launched by different ways including launching with manual steps. Mongo windows server is a way to start mongod automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is generally two  options to start single mongodb database server:

**1. As a console application**

1.1. `mongod --config mongod.conf`

Via this way the configuration parameters are stored in the `mongod.conf` file

1.2. `mongod --port 2000  --dbpath /data/`

Via this way you provide all necessary configurations in command line

**2. As operating system service or daemon**

2.1. Via configuration parameter in the `mongod.conf` file:

```
    processManagement:
      fork: true
```

2.2. Via the operating system services configurations.

This one depends on operating system

The difference is that when you start the mongod as console application  you can see the log messages directly in the screen and you can stop it any time pressing [CTRL]+[C] , this option is preferred for testing , but if you want to run the mongodb permanently you will prefer to execute it as a [service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb).